# Why vs terminal window is not showing react variant?

Tags: reactjs, vite

```
PS C:\Users\shakhawat.hossain07\Desktop\nasaspace_app_challenge> npm create vite@latest
√ Project name: ... nasaspace_app_challenge
√ Select a framework: » React
? Select a variant: » - Use arrow-keys. Return to submit.
>   JavaScript
    TypeScript
```

Why is is not showing like this?:

```
? Select a variant: » - Use arrow-keys. Return to submit.
>   react
    react-ts
```

Please help me to configure this problem

I have installed node.js and run npm create vite@latest command in the terminal window but variant is not showing react just framework is showing react

Answer (score 0):

It might have changed with an update.

Anyways, "react" is "Javascript" and "react-ts" would be "Typescript" in the first prompt